# How to set value using jQuery in different HTML tag scenarios?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to change a value inside different HTML constructs?

In my current code I have:

```
<input type="text" class="value" value="5.0"/>
```

And I use `.each()` and `val()` to change values of class `value`:

```
$(this).val(convert($(this).val(), from, to));
```

Problem arises when I try to do the `convert` function and assign its return value to other HTML constructs like so:

```
<td><span class="value">5.0</span></td>
<td class="value">5.0</td>
```

Despite my value being inside `span` tag, it does not seem to change.  I presume `jQuery.val()` only works for setting the value of an input field, or an attribute, and I can use `jQuery.text()` or `jQuery.html()` to change the value inside the `span` tags....

How do I write code so that I can either figure out which element I am changing, and use appropriate setter method, or use a method that will work for both `input` HTML tag and `span` HTML tags, or even `td`?

Adding a fiddle just in case ... (all should update)

http://jsfiddle.net/dennisfedco/sa82pmwp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Input elements will have a `.value` property. This means you can look for that property and either use it or if it is not present use the text value

```
$('.value').each(function(){
 //if value is not undefined then use val()
 if(this.value != void 0){
  $(this).val(convert($(this).val(),from,to));
 //otherwise use text
 }else{
  $(this).text(convert($(this).text(),from,to));
 }
});
```

Comment: what if `$(this).is('input')` and it can have value attribute but it just not defined or provided? Example: `<input type="text" class="value" />`

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi - `value` is a [property of input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) (and select) elements. Even if it is not set in an attribute it is still present. `$('input')[0].value != void 0` for your example is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the element is an input type with the `:input` selector:

```
$('.value').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':input'))
        $this.val(convert($this.val(), from, to));
    else 
        $this.text(convert($this.text(), from, to));
});
```

Under the hood, jQuery basically tests the element's node name with a little regular expression to see if it's an input element or not, so it should be pretty fast:

```
var rinputs = /^(?:input|select|textarea|button)$/i;
...
return rinputs.test(el.nodeName);
```

Example (code modified to work here):

```js
$('.value').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':input'))
    $this.val($this.val() + " - changed!");
  else
    $this.text($this.text() + " - changed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="value" type="text" value="Initial 1" />
<br />
<span class="value">Initial 2</span>
```

If you wanted to be overly clever about the solution, you could do something like this, where you grab a reference to which function you should be using and then invoke it later:

```
$('.value').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), 
      method = $this.is(':input') ? $this.val : $this.text;
  method.apply($this, [convert(method.apply($this), from, to)]);
});
```

Also:

- [**Here's an update to your jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa82pmwp/5/).

Comment: for some reason I get empty string when I use this ... `alert ($(this).val());` returns nothing when inside the else branch

Comment: @Math, not sure what you mean

Comment: @Dennis my mistake; I was asking if you care about `<select>` elements but `:input` includes those as well. TIL!

Comment: @Dennis `$this.val()` _should_ be empty in the `else` branch, bc the element is _not_ an input. You need `$this.text()`.

Comment: @Dennis: An update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sa82pmwp/5/ (FYI: `<td>` elements cannot exist on their own, which is why I added the rest of the table elements. The script doesn't work otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

An option could be let jQuery make the selection between input and not input values.

```
$('.value:input').each(function(){
    $(this).val(convert($(this).val(), from, to));
});
$('.value').not(':input').each(function(){
    $(this).text(convert($(this).text(), from, to));
});
```

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa82pmwp/4/).